# global sorting across different buckets after aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

a sample in my document is as shown below.
{"rackName" : "rack005", "roomName" : "roomB", "power" : 132, "timestamp" : 1594540106208}

the thing I wanna do is get the latest data of each rack in a given room then sort them by power.
with the code below I did something to get close to my target.losing mind with the last step which seems like soring my data cross different buckets by field 'power'.

```
GET /power/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "roomName.keyword": {
        "value": "roomB"
      }
    }
  }, 
  
  "aggs": {
    "rk_ag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rackName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
              ],
              "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

-----------------------------------result-------------------------------------------------------

```
"aggregations" : {
    "rk_ag" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "rack003",
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "latest" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 4,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "power",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "0FXVQnMB8DPB7H9t6U0E",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "rackName" : "rack003",
                    "roomName" : "roomB",
                    "power" : 115,
                    "timestamp" : 1594540117492
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1594540117492
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "rack004",
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "latest" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 4,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "power",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1FXVQnMB8DPB7H9t6U0E",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "rackName" : "rack004",
                    "roomName" : "roomB",
                    "power" : 108,
                    "timestamp" : 1594540117492
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1594540117492
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "rack005",
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "latest" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 4,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "power",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "2FXVQnMB8DPB7H9t6U0E",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "rackName" : "rack005",
                    "roomName" : "roomB",
                    "power" : 118,
                    "timestamp" : 1594540114492
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1594540114492
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting by `timestamp` instead of `power`. Try this instead:

```
GET /power/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "roomName.keyword": {
        "value": "roomB"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "rk_ag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rackName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "power": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can sort by [multiple fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#search-request-sort) too.

Comment: This doesn't give **latest** (guess date field may come in place)
 data of each rack. It will simply show the document with max power for each rack right!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Joe's answer. As he mentioned, you can use multiple fields in the sort.

Below query would give you what you are looking for:

```
POST my_rack_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "roomName.keyword": {
        "value": "roomB"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "rk_ag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rackName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [                         <---- Note this part
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
              {
                "power": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So now if for every rack you have two documents having **same rackName** with **exact same power**, the one with the *latest timestamp* would be showing up in the response.

The way sort would work is, first it would sort based on the timestamp, then it would do the sorting based on power by keeping the sort based on timestamp intact.

Comment: this may not be what I want.I can not add the second sort filed because I must take out the latest data on of each rack by timestamp.I'm careless of data earlier even though it has bigger power. after the top_hits aggregation,as shown above，I got three buckets whose key are rack003,rack004,rack005.but the order "rack004,rack003,rack005" is what I need because rack004 has the min power 105 and rack005 has the max power 118.